# Regex - starts with a particular string but does not end with another substring

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby

Given two strings `s1` and `s2`, I am trying to write a regex that will match a string that starts with `s1` but does not end with `s2`

Example (s1=TEST, s2=BAD)

- TEST-101  match
- TEST-SOME-DESC match
- TEST-101-BAD should not match
- TEST-SOME-DESC-BAD should not match

Here is what I tried for this example but it does not work: /^TEST-.*((?!BAD))$/

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your suggestion, I improved the question as per your suggestion

Comment: Much better. What about `"TEST-101-SINBAD"`? ([Sinbad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinbad_the_Sailor) being of nautical fame.)

Comment: I know the accepted solution will fail for "TEST-101-SINBAD" (as I would want it to not match). But I got the idea how to write my actual regex.

Comment: If you changed the regex to `/^(?!.+\bBAD$)TEST-.*/`, `\b` being a word break, `"TEST-101-SINBAD"` would be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(?!.+BAD$)TEST-.*/
```

This matches the start, goes ahead and rejects anything ending in the bad string, then matches the desired pattern.

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cgDz2a/1/tests) that passes all four of your tests (click "RUN TESTS" at the bottom to verify).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't understand why the negative look ahead is at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: The problem with putting it at the end is basically that there won't be anything to match. Say your string is `TEST-101-BAD`. In the regex you tried, the `^TEST-.*` piece can match the entire string, including `BAD`. Because that's true, there are no more characters to match, so `(?!BAD)` checks out. Then there's the end of the string (`$`), and so the string passes. What you really want and is perfect for this situation is a "negative lookbehind assertion" (see [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)), but JavaScript's flavor of regular expressions doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startsWith` and `endsWith`

```js
let arr = [`TEST-101`, `TEST-SOME-DESC`,`TEST-101-BAD`,`TEST-SOME-DESC-BAD`]

arr.forEach(e=>{
  console.log(e, e.startsWith('TEST') && !e.endsWith('BAD'))
})
```

Comment: I am looking for a pure regex solution

Answer (score 0):

Use in **JavaScript**:

```js
/^TEST-(?!.*BAD$).*/
```

In **Ruby**:

```rb
/\ATEST-(?!.*BAD\z).*/
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/5cKfg4/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^ / \A                   the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TEST-                    'TEST-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BAD                      'BAD'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $ / \z                   the end of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```